# Flutter get context value from outside context

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter so I'm not sure if my train of thoughts even make sense. I'm currently using a package called [EasyLocalization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) to localize my app. In doing so, I am trying to reference the current locale of my application which is set by EasyLocalization in a service class completely independent of widgets but the only methods offered by the package was to reference the context

In their example, the following code works

```
print(context.locale.toString());
```

However, since I want the value in a "service" class that doesn't make use of widgets, I'm not able to call on any context at all. So something like this code works on my widget but not in an independent service class since context doesn't exist there

```
var currentLocale = EasyLocalization.of(context)?.locale ?? 'en';
```

I've also tried some other code to get the localization but they turn out different from the actual localization my app is sync'ed to. For example when my app is running off 'zh' in EasyLocalization, other methods such as the ones below only return 'en-US'

```
print(Intl().locale);
print(Intl.getCurrentLocale());
```

One way I've gotten it to partially work is to create a function inside my widget that sets a global value when clicked and then reference that value but it feels "hacky" and isn't sufficient for my use-case where data gets loaded on application start which is then passed through a translation function using the context locale. Most other search results also only turn up information for navigation and snackbars which don't seem to help my use-case so I'm currently out of ideas and turning to SO for help.

Below is my MaterialApp() if it helps

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
        child: MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // Todo: Implement dark mode color theme
      theme: lightTheme,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoutes,
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Cant you pass the context to your function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator key to access current context from anywhere. You have to create global key and pass it to material app.

```
//create key
final navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

//pass it to material app
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
        child: MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,  //key
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // Todo: Implement dark mode color theme
      theme: lightTheme,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoutes,
    ));
  }

//access context
print(navigatorKey.currentContext.locale.toString());
```

Comment: How should I reference this value outside of main.dart? I've tried importing it but doesn't seem to work. Calling on MyAppState().navigatorKey.currentContext.locale.toString(); (or MaterialApp().navigatorKey...) says there's no getter for locale. I also tried referencing the EasyLocalization method EasyLocalization.of(MyAppState().navigatorKey.currentContext).locale to reference just the context which returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your service class should be locale independent by design, so taking `locale` as an input, for example:

```
class I18nService {
  final String locale;
  
  I18nService(this.locale);
  
  String sayHello() {
    if (locale == 'en_CA') {
      return 'hello Canada';
    }
    return 'hello world';
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend looking into the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, you can instantiate your service using a `ProxyProvider` and pass in the locale there.

Comment: EasyLocalization has a way of "saving" the locale that has been set persistently through app restarts but I'm not sure how and where that value is stored at or how to access that value outside of a widget (no context). This locale is set using a button and I've tried just setting a variable and then reading it but it feels hacky if I have to use shared preferences. Also I'm trying to avoid having to manage 2 different values so ideally I want to pull it from context if possible